# Return Object from controller to ajax

Tags: ajax, spring

Code below succesfully send String from jsp via ajax to controller and returning some String.

How to send back (from controller to ajax) object which contains only getter and setter or Boolean?

ajax:

```
        $.ajax({
        type: 'get',
        url : 'register/checkUsername',
        data : {'typedText' : typedText},
        success : function(data) {
            $('#doesUsernameAvailable').text("ok " + data);
        },
        error: function(){
            $('#doesUsernameAvailable').text('error');
        }
    });
```

controller:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/checkUsername", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody String checkUsername(String typedText, 
    HttpServletResponse response){

    //some code with return Boolean or Object

    return "text from controller";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

I does not post pom.xml. It was missing:

```
    <dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

And now few modification's.

ajax:

```
            $.ajax({
            type : 'get',
            contentType : "application/json",
            url : 'register/checkUsername',
            data : {'typedText' : typedText},
            dataType : 'json',
            success : function(data) {
                $('#doesUsernameAvailable').text("ok " + data.isAvailable);
            },
            error: function(){
                $('#doesUsernameAvailable').text('error');
            }
        });
```

And now we can return Object from Controller via JSON.

Controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/register")
public class RegisterController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/checkUsername", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody CheckUsernameResponse checkUsername(
    @RequestParam String typedText){

    return new CheckUsernameResponse(true);
}
```

Object:

```
public class CheckUsernameResponse {

    private Boolean isAvailable;

    public CheckUsernameResponse(Boolean isAvailable) {
        this.isAvailable = isAvailable;
    }
```

Hope it help!